# Regarding HTTP ERROR 500 After Clicking button and PhpMailer Email Error

Tags: php, optimization, onsubmit, http-error

```
<?php require('includes/config.php');

//if logged in redirect to members page
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: memberpage.php'); }

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //very basic validation
    if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 3){
        $error[] = 'Username is too short.';
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!empty($row['username'])){
            $error[] = 'Username provided is already in use.';
        }

    }

    if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 3){
        $error[] = 'Password is too short.';
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['passwordConfirm']) < 3){
        $error[] = 'Confirm password is too short.';
    }

    if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['passwordConfirm']){
        $error[] = 'Passwords do not match.';
    }

    //email validation
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = :email');
        $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!empty($row['email'])){
            $error[] = 'Email provided is already in use.';
        }

    }


    //if no errors have been created carry on
    if(!isset($error)){

        //hash the password
        $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        //create the activasion code
        $activasion = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));

        try {

            //insert into database with a prepared statement
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (username,password,email,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :active)');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':username' => $_POST['username'],
                ':password' => $hashedpassword,
                ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                ':active' => $activasion
            ));
            $id = $db->lastInseratId('memberID');

            //send email
            $to = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = "Registration Confirmation";
            $body = "<p>Thank you for registering at demo site.</p>
            <p>To activate your account, please click on this link: <a href='".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion'>".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion</a></p>
            <p>Regards Site Admin</p>";

            $mail = new Mail();
            $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
            $mail->addAddress($to);
            $mail->subject($subject);
            $mail->body($body);
            $mail->send();

            //redirect to index page
            header('Location: index.php?action=joined');
            exit;

        //else catch the exception and show the error.
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>New User Registration</title>

        <meta name="description" content="User login page" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

        <!-- bootstrap & fontawesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

        <!-- text fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/fonts.googleapis.com.css" />

        <!-- ace styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace.min.css" />

        <!--[if lte IE 9]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-part2.min.css" />
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-rtl.min.css" />

        <!--[if lte IE 9]>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-ie.min.css" />
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
<body class="login-layout">
        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div class="login-container">
                            <div class="center">
                                <h1>
                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-leaf green"></i>
                                    <span class="red">Ace</span>
                                    <span class="white" id="id-text2">Application</span>
                                </h1>
                                <h4 class="blue" id="id-company-text">&copy; Company Name</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="space-6"></div>

                            <div class="position-relative">

<div id="signup-box" class="signup-box widget-box no-border visible">
                                    <div class="widget-body">
                                        <div class="widget-main">
                                            <h4 class="header green lighter bigger">
                                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-users blue"></i>
                                                New User Registration
                                            </h4>

                                            <div class="space-6"></div>
                                            <p> Enter your details to begin: </p>

                                            <form role="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
                                    <?php
                                    //check for any errors
                                    if(isset($error)){
                                        foreach($error as $error){
                                            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</p>';
                                        }
                                    }

                                    //if action is joined show sucess
                                    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'joined'){
                                        echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Registration successful, please check your email to activate your account.</h2>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                                <fieldset>
                                                    <label class="block clearfix">
                                                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" tabindex="1">
                                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </label>

                                                    <label class="block clearfix">
                                                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" tabindex="2">
                                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </label>

                                                    <label class="block clearfix">
                                                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" tabindex="3">
                                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lock"></i>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </label>

                                                    <label class="block clearfix">
                                                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                            <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" tabindex="4">
                                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-retweet"></i>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </label>

                                                    <label class="block">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" class="ace">
                                                        <span class="lbl">
                                                            I accept the
                                                            <a href="#">User Agreement</a>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </label>

                                                    <div class="space-24"></div>

                                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                                        <button type="reset" class="width-30 pull-left btn btn-sm">
                                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-refresh"></i>
                                                            <span class="bigger-110">Reset</span>
                                                        </button>

                                                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="width-65 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-success" tabindex="5">
                                                            <span class="bigger-110">Register</span>

                                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right icon-on-right"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </fieldset>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="toolbar center">
                                            <a href="login.html" class="back-to-login-link">
                                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                                                Back to login
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.widget-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.signup-box -->
                                </div><!-- /.position-relative -->

</div>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.main-content -->
        </div><!-- /.main-container -->

        <!-- basic scripts -->

        <!--[if !IE]> -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.2.1.1.min.js"></script>

        <!-- <![endif]-->

        <!--[if IE]>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

        <!--[if !IE]> -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='assets/js/jquery.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
        </script>

        <!-- <![endif]-->

        <!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='assets/js/jquery1x.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
</script>
<![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) document.write("<script src='assets/js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
        </script>

    </body>
</html>

****----------------Here is my Mail.php file-------------------****
<?php    
include('phpmailer.php');
class Mail extends PhpMailer
{
    // Set default variables for all new objects
    public $From     = 'noreply@domain.com';
    public $FromName = SITETITLE;
    public $Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    public $Mailer   = 'isSMTP';
    public $SMTPAuth = true;
    public $Username = 'email@gmail.com';
    public $Password = 'password';
    public $SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    public $WordWrap = 75;

    public function subject($subject)
    {
        $this->Subject = $subject;
    }

    public function body($body)
    {
        $this->Body = $body;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $this->AltBody = strip_tags(stripslashes($this->Body))."\n\n";
        $this->AltBody = str_replace("&nbsp;", "\n\n", $this->AltBody);
        return parent::send();
    }
}
```

****When i submit register button at http://monthlyreport.ultimatefreehost.in I see always HTTP500 Error but the Registration Sql Query save the Data.But the redirect to index page header('Location: index.php?action=joined'); May be not doing the work!!!!**#Solved**

Also the Mail is not being sent always for activation please help me solving this Errrors!!
I am getting email in my inbox like an attachment.Here is email screenshot and attachment File Screenshot---[Email Screenshot][1]
[Email Attachment Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvrd6.png)

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUOEy.png Email Inbox Screenshot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the lastinsertid from the PDO object and not your results object.

Would you please replace `$id = $db->lastInsertId('memberID');' with`$id = $db->lastInseratId('memberID'); ' ?

If you want to redirect with pah use following code.
`header("Location: index.php?action=joined", true, 302);`

You may also redirect with Javascript as well. 
`echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php?action=joined';</script>";`

Would you please try this ?

Comment: Sir i tried yours also!!But same..Would you like to check my Files at yours end ..May i provide you server details?

Comment: Yes, You may provide .

Comment: may you provide yours email id?

Comment: kanani.maulikb@gmail.com

Comment: Details Are sent>>

Comment: Okay, Would you please come to hangout ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
header('Location:index.php?action=joined');
```

Comment: Still Same Problem Sir!!!!Can you see my Php mailer codealso may be it is causing error

Comment: just comment your email sending code and then try it

Comment: first comment the `mail` code to see if rest is working or not and if found any problem in `mail` then try [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/) for phpmailer

Comment: you might be having problem with your .htaccess file . please check that file

Comment: generally `HTTP 500 - Server error` occurs when `ajax` is not fire, make your ajax call proper see in Browser Console to check whether `ajax` called or not !